# How to rig flaps

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I have modeled a simple air plane. It has flaps. I would like to easily animate the flaps. THe flaps are part of the plane mesh. How can I rig the flaps so that I have a single control for the flaps?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add a bone object, place it so that the header is on the hinge axis.
2. First select the mesh object, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the bone, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > With Empty Groups.
3. Select all vertices on the flap, Click **Assign** on the *Vertex Groups* panel, so that the flap will be singly controlled by the bone.
4. Fore more flaps, you need to add more bones for the armature in step 1.

[image]

[image]

NOTE: You need to enter **Pose Mode** to control the bone(s).

Comment: This does not work for me, here is what I did.
Add bone, Place bone
,Select mesh than bone.
,Parent with empty groups
,Select mesh
,in edit mode select flap
,In vertex groups assign to bone

- The entire mesh is rotating with the bone

Comment: @Vader It should work. In that case, I'm curious about what you exactly made. Will you upload the file?

Comment: It really works good to me by following the steps above. What I mean actually is whether you could upload the final rigged file, which is problematic as you mentioned.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, turns out I was rotating the bone in object mode rather that pose mode.

Comment: Yes. Because the armature becomes parent here. You can either add another bone to control the body part, or, I personally suggest to separate flaps as individual meshes for easy control, and you can finally parent the armature(s) to the body (of course, you can do this without bones by doing so).